# tesseract ocr command line for signe character

Tags: command-line, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying run tesseract-ocr over this image, unsuccessfully :

[image: 6]

```
> wget https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXR44.png
...
> convert dOtlrvx.png dOtlrvx.tif
> tesseract dOtlrvx.tif out -psm 10 && cat out.txt
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.02 with Leptonica
Page 0
.
```

The recognized char is a dot "."

-psm 10 stands for "treat the image as a single character" so I think its the correct option to use. I also tried with other psm possible values, it does not work neither.

Anyone has an idea why is this not working ? Any suggestion is welcomed !

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new config file for tesseract, add this line `tessedit_char_whitelist 0123456789` and then process your image: `tesseract dOtlrvx.tif out -psm 10 your_config_file`.

This worked for me.